# Android - Playing song when listview item is clicked

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

I am trying to implement a music player application (given in tutsplus.com) I am getting this following exception :

```
06-19 12:28:06.457 14867-14867/com.example.adityakrishnakumar.mymusicplayer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.adityakrishnakumar.mymusicplayer, PID: 14867
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3978)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4646)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19403)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5511)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3973)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4646) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19403) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5511) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.adityakrishnakumar.mymusicplayer.MainActivity.songPicked(MainActivity.java:98)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3973) 
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4646) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19403) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5511) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The code for MainActivity is as follows :

```
    package com.example.adityakrishnakumar.mymusicplayer;

    import android.content.ComponentName;
    import android.content.ContentResolver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.ServiceConnection;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.IBinder;
    import android.provider.MediaStore;
    import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
    import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.MediaController;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.Comparator;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MediaController.MediaPlayerControl{

    private ArrayList<Song> songList;
    private ListView songView;
    private MusicService musicService;
    private Intent playIntent;
    private boolean musicBound = false;
    private MusicController controller;
    private boolean paused = false, playbackPaused = false;

    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        paused = true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        if(paused){
            setController();
            paused = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop(){
        controller.hide();
        super.onStop();
    }

    private void setController(){
     controller = new MusicController(this);
        controller.setPrevNextListeners(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                playNext();
            }
        }, new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                playPrev();
            }
        });
        controller.setMediaPlayer(this);
        controller.setAnchorView(findViewById(R.id.song_list));
        controller.setEnabled(true);
    }

    private void playPrev() {
        musicService.playPrev();
        if(playbackPaused){
            setController();
            playbackPaused = false;
        }
        controller.show(0);
    }

    private void playNext() {
        musicService.playNext();
        if(playbackPaused){
            setController();
            playbackPaused = false;
        }
        controller.show(0);
    }

    public void songPicked(View view)
    {
        int songIndex = Integer.parseInt(view.getTag().toString());
        musicService.setSong(songIndex);
        musicService.playSong();
        if(playbackPaused){
            setController();
            playbackPaused = false;
        }
        controller.show(0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        setController();
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        songView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.song_list);
        songList = new ArrayList<Song>();
        getSongList();

        //Displaying the songs

        Collections.sort(songList, new Comparator<Song>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Song lhs, Song rhs) {
                return lhs.getTitle().compareTo(rhs.getTitle());
            }
        });

        SongAdapter songAdapter = new SongAdapter(this,songList);
        songView.setAdapter(songAdapter);
    }

    private ServiceConnection musicConnection = new ServiceConnection(){

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            MusicService.MusicBinder binder = (MusicService.MusicBinder) service;
            // get service
            musicService = binder.getService();
            //pass the list
            musicService.setList(songList);
            musicBound = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            musicBound = false;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        if(playIntent == null)
        {
            playIntent = new Intent(this, MusicService.class);
            bindService(playIntent, musicConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
            startService(playIntent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.action_shuffle:
                musicService.setShuffle();
                break;
            case R.id.action_end:
                stopService(playIntent);
                musicService = null;
                System.exit(0);
                break;
        }

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void getSongList()
    {
        // retrieve song info
        ContentResolver musicResolver = getContentResolver();
        Uri musicUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri,null,null,null,null);
        int idColumn = 0;
        int titleColumn = 0;
        int artistColumn = 0;

        // Checking whether we have valid data

        if(musicCursor != null && musicCursor.moveToFirst())
            {
                titleColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
                idColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
                artistColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
            }
        // Adding songs to list
        do
            {
                long thisID = musicCursor.getLong(idColumn);
                String thisTitle = musicCursor.getString(titleColumn);
                String thisArtist = musicCursor.getString(artistColumn);
                songList.add(new Song(thisID,thisTitle,thisArtist));
            } while(musicCursor.moveToNext());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        stopService(playIntent);
        musicService = null;
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        musicService.go();
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
        playbackPaused = true;
        musicService.pausePlayer();
    }

    @Override
    public int getDuration() {
        if(musicService != null && musicBound && musicService.isPng())
        {
            return musicService.getDur();
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCurrentPosition() {
        if(musicService != null && musicBound && musicService.isPng())
        {
            return musicService.getPosn();
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void seekTo(int pos) {
        musicService.seek(pos);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isPlaying() {
        if(musicService != null && musicBound)
        {
            return musicService.isPng();
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getBufferPercentage() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canPause() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canSeekBackward() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canSeekForward() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int getAudioSessionId() {
        return 0;
    }

    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)
    {

    }
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int a, int b)
    {
        return false;
    }
    }
```

The Custom MusicService Java class is as follows :

```
    package com.example.adityakrishnakumar.mymusicplayer;

    import android.app.Notification;
    import android.app.PendingIntent;
    import android.app.Service;
    import android.content.ContentUris;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.media.AudioManager;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Binder;
    import android.os.IBinder;
    import android.os.PowerManager;
    import android.provider.MediaStore;
    import android.util.Log;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Random;

    public class MusicService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener,MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener{
    private static final int NOTIFY_ID = 1;
    private String songTitle = null;

    private boolean shuffle = false;
    private Random rand;

    public MusicService() {
    }
    private MediaPlayer player;
    private ArrayList<Song> songs;
    private int songPosn;
    private final IBinder musicBind = new MusicBinder();

    public IBinder onIBind(Intent intent){
        return musicBind;
    }

    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent){
        player.stop();
        player.release();
        return false;
    }

    public void playSong(){
        player.reset();
        Song playSong = songs.get(songPosn);
        songTitle = playSong.getTitle();
        long currSong = playSong.getId();
        Uri trackUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,currSong);
        try{
            player.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), trackUri);
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("MUSIC SERVICE","Error Setting Data Source",e);
        }
        player.prepareAsync();
    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            if(player.getCurrentPosition() > 0)
            {
                mp.reset();
                playNext();
            }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        // create service
        super.onCreate();
        //initialize position
        rand = new Random();
        songPosn = 0;
        player = new MediaPlayer();
        initMusicPlayer();

    }

    public void setShuffle(){
        if(shuffle) shuffle = false;
        else
            shuffle = true;
    }

    public void initMusicPlayer(){
        player.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
        player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        player.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        player.setOnErrorListener(this);
    }

    public void setList(ArrayList<Song> theSongs)
    {
        songs = theSongs;
    }

    public class MusicBinder extends Binder{
        MusicService getService(){
            return MusicService.this;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        mp.reset();
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
    {
    mp.start();
        Intent notIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        notIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,notIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);

        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.play)
                .setTicker(songTitle)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setContentTitle("Playing")
                .setContentText(songTitle);
        Notification not = builder.build();
        startForeground(NOTIFY_ID,not);
    }

    public void setSong(int songIndex)
    {
        songPosn = songIndex;
    }

    public int getPosn()
    {
        return player.getCurrentPosition();
    }
    public int getDur()
    {
        return player.getDuration();
    }
    public boolean isPng()
    {
        return player.isPlaying();
    }
    public void pausePlayer(){
        player.pause();
    }
    public void seek(int posn)
    {
        player.seekTo(posn);
    }
    public void go()
    {
        player.start();
    }
    public void playPrev()
    {
        songPosn--;
        if(songPosn < 0 )
        {
            songPosn = songs.size()-1;
        }
        playSong();
    }
    public void playNext(){
        if(shuffle)
        {
            int newSong = songPosn;
            while(newSong == songPosn)
            {
                newSong = rand.nextInt(songs.size());
            }
            songPosn = newSong;
        }
        else
        {
            songPosn++;
            if(songPosn >= songs.size()) songPosn = 0;
        }
        playSong();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        stopForeground(true);
    }
    }
```

The SongAdapter (that stores the music info is as follows :

```
    package com.example.adityakrishnakumar.mymusicplayer;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class SongAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<Song> songs;
    private LayoutInflater songInf;

    public SongAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Song> theSongs)
    {
        songs = theSongs;
        songInf = LayoutInflater.from(c);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return songs.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // map to song layout
        LinearLayout songLay = (LinearLayout)songInf.inflate(R.layout.song,parent,false);
        //Get Title and artist views
        TextView songView = (TextView) songLay.findViewById(R.id.song_title);
        TextView artistView = (TextView) songLay.findViewById(R.id.song_artist);
        // get the song using position
        Song currSong = songs.get(position);
        // Get Title & Artist Strings
        songView.setText(currSong.getTitle());
        artistView.setText(currSong.getArtist());
        // Set Position as tag
        songLay.setTag(position);
        return songLay;
    }
    }
```

The Controller for music playback (MusicController) is as follows :

```
    package com.example.adityakrishnakumar.mymusicplayer;

    import android.annotation.TargetApi;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.widget.MediaController;
    import android.os.Build;

    public class MusicController extends MediaController {

    public MusicController(Context c)
    {
        super(c);
    }
    public void hide(){}
    }
```

I have also given the following permissions in Manifest :

```
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

The XML that gives the song name and artist name is as follows (song.xml)

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:onClick="songPicked"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/song_title"
        android:textColor="#ffffff99"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/song_artist"
        android:textColor="#ffffff99"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have get `NullPointerExeception` on this line.

```
 int songIndex = Integer.parseInt(view.getTag().toString());
```

first check that `view.getTag().toString()` is null or not.

write this way

```
 public void songPicked(View view)
    {  
       if(view.getTag().toString() != null){
          int songIndex = Integer.parseInt(view.getTag().toString());
        }
        musicService.setSong(songIndex);
        musicService.playSong();
        if(playbackPaused){
            setController();
            playbackPaused = false;
        }
        controller.show(0);
    }
```

Comment: songIndex is 0 and MusicService object is null.  @Ironman, what's next ? am i missing something ?

Comment: your `MusicService` object is `null` or `empty` and you are access it so that's why it give `NullPointerExecption`.

Comment: @AdityaKrishnakumar you can accept answer if this answer is useful to you.